# Reading Parquet columns as RDD rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd, parquet

Is there a way to read **columns** from a Parquet file as **rows** in a Spark RDD, materializing the full contents of each column as a list within an RDD tuple?

The idea is that for cases where I need to run a non-distributable, in-memory-only algorithm (processing a full column of data) on a set of executors, I would like to be able to parallelize the processing by shipping the full contents of each column to the executors. My initial implementation, which involved reading the Parquet file as a `DataFrame`, then converting it to `RDD` and transposing the rows via `aggregateByKey`, has turned out to be too expensive in terms of time (probably due to the extensive shuffling required).

If possible, I would prefer to use an existing implementation, rather than rolling my own implementations of [ParquetInputFormat](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetInputFormat.java), [ReadSupport](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/api/ReadSupport.java), and/or [RecordMaterializer](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-column/src/main/java/parquet/io/api/RecordMaterializer.java).

Suggestions for alternative approaches are welcome as well.

Comment: Why dont you use `DataSet` for this? also did you try Window functions?

Comment: @Shankar I didn't think to mention it in the original question wording, but the motivation for seeking to read the Parquet in this way is to make the full column data available to existing number-crunching routines written in Python atop NumPy and Pandas. Therefore, I'm using PySpark, which does not make `DataSet` available. The fact that I'm using PySpark also makes `groupBy` / windowing less attractive as a solution, as PySpark does not (yet?) implement UDAFs: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10915.

Comment: +1 Frequently need parallelism over columns, not rows! Useful to be able to efficiently load full column into core.